# Hl7 FHIR Extensions: nesting, slicing, ids and discriminators

Tags: hl7-fhir

Due to a (somehow) special requirement to store data alongside a FHIR resource, I am looking for the cleanest way to extend it to maintain such extra data, which is basically dynamic key-value lists.

On the one hand I have something like the following, with 0..* sets of key-value, that I have tried to store nesting three extensions (adjusting the context by level) being the last a single limitation to the accepted types (string/integer), although it does not allow me to repeat ids, anyway I am getting around it using prefixes XD.

```
"n-lists-of-key-value": [
  {
    "list1-key1": "list1-value1",
    "list1-key2": "list1-value1",
    "list1-key3": "list1-value1"
  },
  {
    "list2-key1": "list2-value1",
    "list2-key2": "list2-value2"
  }
]
```

becomes:

```
···,
  "extension": [ {
    "id": "n-lists-of-key-value",
    "url": "http://x.org/fhir/Extension/NListOfKeyValueExtension",
    "extension": [ {
      "id": "list_1",
      "url": "http://x.org/fhir/Extension/ListKeyValueExtension,
      "extension": [ {
        "id": "list1-key1",
        "url": "http://x.org/fhir/Extension/KeyValueExtension,
        "valueString": "list1-value1"
      }, {
        "id": "list1-key2",
        "url": "http://x.org/fhir/Extension/KeyValueExtension,
        "valueString": "list1-value1"
      }, {
        "id": "list1-key3",
        "url": "http://x.org/fhir/Extension/KeyValueExtension,
        "valueString": "list1-value1"
      } ]
    }, {
      "id": "list_2",
      "url": "http://x.org/fhir/Extension/ListKeyValueExtension,
      "extension": [ {
        "id": "list2-key1",
        "url": "http://x.org/fhir/Extension/KeyValueExtension,
        "valueString": "list2-value1"
      }, {
        "id": "list2-key2",
        "url": "http://x.org/fhir/Extension/KeyValueExtension,
        "valueString": "list2-value2"
      } ]
    } ]
  } ],
```

But on the other hand I have this, which is what I find most difficult to model, because trying to reuse the extension definitions I run into (conceptual?) difficulties with slicing and the use of the discriminators, failing to get past the error "Element matches more than one slice".

```
"my-3-fixed-named-sets": {
  "fixed-named-set1": {
    "list1-key1": "list1-value1",
    "list1-key2": "list1-value2",
    "list1-key3": "list1-value3"
  },
  "fixed-named-set2": {
    "list2-key1": "list2-value1",
    "list2-key2": "list2-value2"
  },
  "fixed-named-set3": {
    "list2-key1": "list2-value1",
    "list2-key2": "list2-value2"
  }
}
```

becomes:

```
···,
  "extension": [ {
    "id": "my-3-fixed-named-sets",
    "url": "http://x.org/fhir/Extension/NListOfKeyValueExtension",
    "extension": [ {
      "id": "fixed-named-set1",
      "url": "http://x.org/fhir/Extension/ListKeyValueExtension,
      "extension": [ {
        "id": "list1-key1",
        "url": "http://x.org/fhir/Extension/KeyValueExtension,
        "valueString": "list1-value1"
      }, {
        "id": "list1-key2",
        "url": "http://x.org/fhir/Extension/KeyValueExtension,
        "valueString": "list1-value2"
      }, {
        "id": "list1-key3",
        "url": "http://x.org/fhir/Extension/KeyValueExtension,
        "valueString": "list1-value3"
      } ]
    }, {
      "id": "fixed-named-set2",
      "url": "http://x.org/fhir/Extension/ListKeyValueExtension,
      "extension": [ {
        "id": "list2-key1",
        "url": "http://x.org/fhir/Extension/KeyValueExtension,
        "valueString": "list2-value1"
      }, {
        "id": "list2-key2",
        "url": "http://x.org/fhir/Extension/KeyValueExtension,
        "valueString": "list2-value2"
      } ],
      }, {
      "id": "fixed-named-set3",
      "url": "http://x.org/fhir/Extension/ListKeyValueExtension,
      "extension": [ {
        "id": "list2-key1",
        "url": "http://x.org/fhir/Extension/KeyValueExtension,
        "valueString": "list2-value1"
      }, {
        "id": "list2-key3",
        "url": "http://x.org/fhir/Extension/KeyValueExtension,
        "valueString": "list2-value3"
      } ]
    } ]
  } ],
```

I am aware that by indiscriminately including new extensions with different names/urls, I can end up ingesting all the data, but I suspect that there is a much cleaner way and that I am failing in , probably, the way to include an extra condition into the discriminator (https://hl7.org/fhir/profiling.html#slicing), so that I could point to the proper slide? or de fact of extending extensions or extending value[x] slices?

```
"discriminator": [
            {
              "type": "value",
              "path": "url"
            },
            {  "???": "??Extension.value.slideName??
···
```

Then my specific question would be... can I slice the value[x] of the extension of a specific profile, and which in turn make them extensions? this lasy is to get having n key value lists

Any comment is very welcome :)

Comment: Maybe the problem is that I am mixing "extend the extension" and "extend -the value[x] of the extension" ?

Comment: In your examples, I'm not seeing the use of 'extension' at all - I would have expected to see 'url' and 'value' or child extensions.

Comment: Extensions means that you're using the 'extension' element.  You're not allowed to introduce new element names, only extension elements with URLs and values (possibly nested)

Comment: sorry @LloydMcKenzie , the jsons was only to ilustrate the kind of info i am trying to move to extensions/slices structure

Comment: Ok, that helps.  You can't use the 'id' as the key for your extension.  You need to do one of two things:
- define extension URLs for each 'name'
- have a complex extension with two sub-extension - one for name and one for value.

'id' has no semantics.  It's solely used to do things like tie narrative to discrete data.